# Beanstalk rebuild app servers only and without affecting RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I have an application deployed on AWS using Beanstalk, it contains mainly the application servers and an RDS instance.

For a reason, I want to rebuild that app servers without touching the RDS instance.

Is there another way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!** An easy workaround can be done by updating the auto scaling group.

Steps:

1. Update the auto scaling group to have the desired, minimum, and maximum capacity with zero value.
2. Wait few minutes till all the instances being terminated.
3. Restore the auto scaling group parameters to the old values.
4. Wait few minutes till the new instances being built.